# Проблема в действии программы, если во входных данных в строке последние буквы

Tags: java

Программа должна переворачивать куски буквенных данных, оставляя цифры и знаки на месте, все переворачивает, но если в конце не буквы.
Ошибка в условии цикла, но не знаю как исправить. При исправлении `<` на `<=` выскакивает ошибка:

> String index out of range

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Anagramm {  
    public static void main(String args[])  
{  
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //это сканнер  
    System.out.println("Введите строку");  
    String string = scanner.nextLine();  
    String first = new String(); //стек строки первичных данных  
    int stringLenght = string.length(); //значение длины строки для счетчика   цикла  
    for (int i=0; i<stringLenght; i++){  
         char myChar = string.charAt(i);  
         char type=simbolType(myChar); //тип анализируемого символа, отсыл к методу simbolType   
    if (type=='l'){  
        first=first+myChar;  
             }   //образование первичной строки, прямой  
    else if (type=='d') {  
             String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();  
             System.out.print(r);  
             first = "";  
             int z = Character.getNumericValue(myChar);  
             System.out.print(z);  
                    } //print digit  
         else if (type=='w') {   
                  String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();  
                  System.out.print(r);  
                  first = "";  
                  System.out.print(" ");  
                        }  
              else {  
                  String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();  
                  System.out.print(r);  
                  first = "";  
                  System.out.print(myChar);  
                   }
    //условие для формирования блока для анаграммы

    char k=type;
    if (k!='l'){
        String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
        System.out.print(r);
        first = "";
            }
    else {}
                            }

}

public static char simbolType(char unknownSymbol) //блок определения типа символа
{
    char hisType;
    if (Character.isLetter(unknownSymbol)==true) {
                                                  hisType='l';  //тип символа буква
                                                 }
    else if (Character.isDigit(unknownSymbol)==true){
                                                     hisType='d'; //тип символа цифра
                                                    }
         else if (Character.isWhitespace(unknownSymbol)==true){
                                                               hisType='w';   //тип символа пробел
                                                              }
              else {
                    hisType='a';  // тип символа другой "any"
                   }
    return hisType;
}



                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

В цикле у вас формируется строка из букв, которую надо обратить. Само обращение происходит только при условии, что следующий символ пробел или цифра. Т.о. если строка заканчивается на буквы и она подошла к концу - обращения нет (да и вообще вывода этой части). Чтобы это исправить можно **после** цикла надо добавить обработку с условием, что есть не выведенные символы.

```
if (!first.isEmpty()) {
    String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
    System.out.print(r);
    first = "";
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, Николай!!

Answer (score 0):

Попробую написать развернутый ответ с указанием на недостатки и возможными решениями их.

Для начала ваш же код только отформатированный к более удобо читаемому виду. Для более подробного ознакомления прочтите [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Anagramm {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // это сканнер

        System.out.println("Введите строку");

        String string = scanner.nextLine();
        String first = new String(); // стек строки первичных данных
        int stringLenght = string.length(); // значение длины строки для счетчика цикла

        for (int i = 0; i < stringLenght; i++) {
            char myChar = string.charAt(i);
            char type = simbolType(myChar); // тип анализируемого символа, отсыл к методу simbolType

            if (type == 'l') {
                first = first + myChar; // образование первичной строки, прямой
            } else if (type == 'd') {
                String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
                System.out.print(r);
                first = "";
                int z = Character.getNumericValue(myChar);
                System.out.print(z); // print digit
            } else if (type == 'w') {
                String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
                System.out.print(r);
                first = "";
                System.out.print(" ");
            } else {
                String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
                System.out.print(r);
                first = "";
                System.out.print(myChar);
            }

            // условие для формирования блока для анаграммы
            char k = type;

            if (k != 'l') {
                String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
                System.out.print(r);
                first = "";
            } else {}
        }
    }

    public static char simbolType(char unknownSymbol) { // блок определения типа символа
        char hisType;

        if (Character.isLetter(unknownSymbol) == true) {
            hisType = 'l'; // тип символа буква
        } else if (Character.isDigit(unknownSymbol) == true) {
            hisType = 'd'; // тип символа цифра
        } else if (Character.isWhitespace(unknownSymbol) == true) {
            hisType = 'w'; // тип символа пробел
        } else {
            hisType = 'a'; // тип символа другой "any"
        }

        return hisType;
    }
}
```

Переменная `stringLenght` используется единожды в условии цикла, опустим её определение и вычислим длину строки прямо в условии цикла.

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) { ... }
```

Код форматирующий вывод результата, состоящий из блоков условий `if`, `else if`, `else`, можно переписать с использование `switch`, благодаря чему код будет выглядеть чище.

```
switch (type) {
    case 'l':
        first = first + myChar; // образование первичной строки, прямой
        break;
    case 'd':
        String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
        System.out.print(r);
        first = "";
        int z = Character.getNumericValue(myChar);
        System.out.print(z); // print digit
        break;
    case 'w':
        String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
        System.out.print(r);
        first = "";
        System.out.print(" ");
        break;
    default:
        String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
        System.out.print(r);
        first = "";
        System.out.print(myChar);
}
```

Некоторые действия в блоках `d`, `w`, `default` повторяются, можно их оптимизировать и объединить.

```
switch (type) {
    case 'l':
        first += myChar; // образование первичной строки, прямой
        break;
    case 'd':
    case 'w':
    default:
        String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
        first = "";

        System.out.print(r);
        System.out.print(myChar);
}
```

В этом куске кода ничего не происходит, т.к. на входе в `if` переменная `first` всегда пуста. Можно смело его удалять.

```
char k = type;

if (k != 'l') {
    String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
    System.out.print(r);
    first = "";
} else {}
```

В итоге мы получили такой код.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Anagramm {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // это сканнер

        System.out.println("Введите строку");

        String string = scanner.nextLine();
        String first = new String(); // стек строки первичных данных

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            char myChar = string.charAt(i);
            char type = simbolType(myChar); // тип анализируемого символа, отсыл к методу simbolType

            switch (type) {
                case 'l':
                    first += myChar; // образование первичной строки, прямой
                    break;
                case 'd':
                case 'w':
                default:
                    String r = new StringBuffer(first).reverse().toString();
                    first = "";

                    System.out.print(r);
                    System.out.print(myChar);
            }
        }
    }

    public static char simbolType(char unknownSymbol) { // блок определения типа символа
        char hisType;

        if (Character.isLetter(unknownSymbol) == true) {
            hisType = 'l'; // тип символа буква
        } else if (Character.isDigit(unknownSymbol) == true) {
            hisType = 'd'; // тип символа цифра
        } else if (Character.isWhitespace(unknownSymbol) == true) {
            hisType = 'w'; // тип символа пробел
        } else {
            hisType = 'a'; // тип символа другой "any"
        }

        return hisType;
    }
}
```